# Adding rows to the Datatable in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, datatable, datarow

I am working on a project and i want to add rows to the Datatable and what is happening is if i am  fetching two rows from the database only one of the two is being added to the datatable but i want both to be added to the datatable i.e the datatable is not able to hold the  data of first row,the data is being overwrite by data of second row.
the code of the method is.
this is my calling statement.

```
    DataTable dttable = new DataTable();
    dttable = gettable(dtgreater, dtcurrentdate);
    public DataTable gettable(List<DateTime> objct1, DateTime objct2)
    {

    DataTable data=null;
    for (int j = 0; j < dtgreater.Count; j++)
    {
        sql = "select library_issue.STUDENTCODE,library_issue.studentname,library_book.bookname,library_issue.issuedate,library_issue.returndate from library_issue             join library_book on library_book.book_id = library_issue.book_id where library_issue.returndate ='" + objct1[j].ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "'";
        ds = obj.openDataset(sql, Session["SCHOOLCODE"].ToString());
        Label1.Text = (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count).ToString();
        data = new DataTable();
        data.Columns.Add("STUDENTCODE", typeof(int));
        data.Columns.Add("Studentname", typeof(string));
        data.Columns.Add("Bookname", typeof(string));
        data.Columns.Add("Issuedate", typeof(string));
        data.Columns.Add("Returndate", typeof(string));
        data.Columns.Add("NO of Days Exceeded", typeof(string));
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            TimeSpan ts = objct1[j] - objct2;
            Label1.Text = ts.ToString("dd");
            data.Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["STUDENTCODE"], ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["studentname"], ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["bookname"], ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["issuedate"], ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["returndate"], ts.ToString("dd"));

        }

    }

     return data;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
   public DataTable gettable(List<DateTime> objct1, DateTime objct2)
    {

        DataTable data = new DataTable();

        data.Columns.Add("STUDENTCODE", typeof(int));
        data.Columns.Add("Studentname", typeof(string));
        data.Columns.Add("Bookname", typeof(string));
        data.Columns.Add("Issuedate", typeof(string));
        data.Columns.Add("Returndate", typeof(string));
        data.Columns.Add("NO of Days Exceeded", typeof(string));
    for (int j = 0; j < dtgreater.Count; j++)
    {
        sql = "select library_issue.STUDENTCODE,library_issue.studentname,library_book.bookname,library_issue.issuedate,library_issue.returndate from library_issue             join library_book on library_book.book_id = library_issue.book_id where library_issue.returndate ='" + objct1[j].ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "'";
        ds = obj.openDataset(sql, Session["SCHOOLCODE"].ToString());
        Label1.Text = (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count).ToString();

        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            TimeSpan ts = objct1[j] - objct2;
            Label1.Text = ts.ToString("dd");
            data.Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["STUDENTCODE"], ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["studentname"], ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["bookname"], ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["issuedate"], ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["returndate"], ts.ToString("dd"));

        }

    }

     return data;
}
```

**Discription:** As I was initializing the datatable inside the for loop which was causing the creation of new instance of datatable each time .
 As a result of which i was getting only one rows each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating the data table inside the loop, so in the second iteration it will discard the first data table with the first item and create a new empty one for the second item.

Create the data table and add the columns to it before the loop:

```
DataTable dttable = new DataTable();
dttable = gettable(dtgreater, dtcurrentdate);

public DataTable gettable(List<DateTime> objct1, DateTime objct2)
{

  DataTable data = new DataTable();
  data.Columns.Add("STUDENTCODE", typeof(int));
  data.Columns.Add("Studentname", typeof(string));
  data.Columns.Add("Bookname", typeof(string));
  data.Columns.Add("Issuedate", typeof(string));
  data.Columns.Add("Returndate", typeof(string));
  data.Columns.Add("NO of Days Exceeded", typeof(string));
  for (int j = 0; j < dtgreater.Count; j++) {
    sql = "select library_issue.STUDENTCODE,library_issue.studentname,library_book.bookname,library_issue.issuedate,library_issue.returndate from library_issue             join library_book on library_book.book_id = library_issue.book_id where library_issue.returndate ='" + objct1[j].ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "'";
    ds = obj.openDataset(sql, Session["SCHOOLCODE"].ToString());
    Label1.Text = (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count).ToString();
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++) {

        TimeSpan ts = objct1[j] - objct2;
        Label1.Text = ts.ToString("dd");
        data.Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["STUDENTCODE"], ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["studentname"], ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["bookname"], ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["issuedate"], ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["returndate"], ts.ToString("dd"));

    }

  }

  return data;
}
```

Comment: i updated my code according to ur suggestion but i got an error as A column named 'STUDENTCODE' already belongs to this DataTable.

Comment: @Ashish: Where do you get that error? There is only one place where the column is added, and that is immediately after a new, empty data table is created.

Answer (score 1):

Place the table creation outside of the loop.

```
DataTable data = new DataTable();
```

It is probably better to use a `foreach` like this:

For example:

```
foreach (var dr in ds.Tables.First().Rows)
{
   string studentCode = dr["STUDENTCODE"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line :   `data = new DataTable();`

Create the Datatable outside the For loop like below...

```
    DataTable data = new DataTable();
    data.Columns.Add("STUDENTCODE", typeof(int));
    data.Columns.Add("Studentname", typeof(string));
    data.Columns.Add("Bookname", typeof(string));
    data.Columns.Add("Issuedate", typeof(string));
    data.Columns.Add("Returndate", typeof(string));
    data.Columns.Add("NO of Days Exceeded", typeof(string))
    for (int j = 0; j < dtgreater.Count; j++)
     {
```

it will solve your problem...

Comment: i updated my code according to ur suggestion but i got an error as A column named 'STUDENTCODE' already belongs to this DataTable.

Comment: @Ashish: In the run time at which line you got this error...? Can you point that line

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is

```
    DataTable dttable = new DataTable();
    dttable = gettable(dtgreater, dtcurrentdate);
    public DataTable gettable(List<DateTime> objct1, DateTime objct2)
    {

    DataTable data=null;
    for (int j = 0; j < dtgreater.Count; j++)
    {
        sql = "select library_issue.STUDENTCODE,library_issue.studentname,library_book.bookname,library_issue.issuedate,library_issue.returndate from library_issue             join library_book on library_book.book_id = library_issue.book_id where library_issue.returndate ='" + objct1[j].ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "'";
        ds = obj.openDataset(sql, Session["SCHOOLCODE"].ToString());
        Label1.Text = (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count).ToString();
       if(data.Columns.count==0)
        {
        data = new DataTable();
        data.Columns.Add("STUDENTCODE", typeof(int));
        data.Columns.Add("Studentname", typeof(string));
        data.Columns.Add("Bookname", typeof(string));
        data.Columns.Add("Issuedate", typeof(string));
        data.Columns.Add("Returndate", typeof(string));
        data.Columns.Add("NO of Days Exceeded", typeof(string));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            TimeSpan ts = objct1[j] - objct2;
            Label1.Text = ts.ToString("dd");
            data.Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["STUDENTCODE"], ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["studentname"], ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["bookname"], ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["issuedate"], ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["returndate"], ts.ToString("dd"));

        }

    }

     return data;
}
```

I guess this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dttable = new DataTable();
dttable = gettable(dtgreater, dtcurrentdate);
public DataTable gettable(List<DateTime> objct1, DateTime objct2)
{
    DataTable data=null;
    sql = "select library_issue.STUDENTCODE,library_issue.studentname,library_book.bookname,library_issue.issuedate,library_issue.returndate from library_issue             join library_book on library_book.book_id = library_issue.book_id where library_issue.returndate ='" + objct1[j].ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "'";
    ds = obj.openDataset(sql, Session["SCHOOLCODE"].ToString());
    Label1.Text = (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count).ToString();


for (int j = 0; j < dtgreater.Count; j++)
{
   if(data.Columns.count==0)
    {
    data = new DataTable();
    data.Columns.Add("STUDENTCODE", typeof(int));
    data.Columns.Add("Studentname", typeof(string));
    data.Columns.Add("Bookname", typeof(string));
    data.Columns.Add("Issuedate", typeof(string));
    data.Columns.Add("Returndate", typeof(string));
    data.Columns.Add("NO of Days Exceeded", typeof(string));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        TimeSpan ts = objct1[j] - objct2;
        Label1.Text = ts.ToString("dd");
        data.Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["STUDENTCODE"], ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["studentname"], ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["bookname"], ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["issuedate"], ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["returndate"], ts.ToString("dd"));

}
 return data;
}
```

Comment: A short description of what you've done and why will go a long way - nobody likes playing *"spot the difference"*.

Answer (score 0):

```
Var.GRV.Columns.Add("NAME COLUMN");
            Var.GRV.Columns.Add("NAME COLUMN");
            Var.GRV.Columns.Add("*");
            Var.GRV.Columns.Add("*");
            Var.GRV.Columns.Add("*");
```